# Spring Boot Configuration Metadata for @ConfigurationProperties classes are not generated for Maps with Nested Properties classes as Value

Tags: spring-boot

Spring Boot 3.1.4

Generating meta data stops at Map. I can understand that it does so for simple types and enums(which i am quite happy to define through hints), but what about complex types. Further config properties classes? Surely this is where the power of **@ConfigurationProperties** lies? I have properties files nested several layers deep. Works perfectly fine, but there is no MetaData to rely on.

This renders the library almost useless(for me) since i use meta data to drive a setup wizard where users can configure their env.

Now, before i start writing my own lib, am i missing something? The docs seem to be quite clear on Map values as enums/other simple types, but not pojo's as value.
Any ideas? Much appreciated!

[Configuration Metadata](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/configuration-metadata.html#appendix.configuration-metadata.format)

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-boot-configuration-processor</artifactId>
   <optional>true</optional>
</dependency>
```

EXAMPLE:

```
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "cache.cfg")
public class CacheCfgProps {

   /**
    * Cache properties map. Cache Name is the key.
    */
    @Getter
    private HashMap<String, CacheProps> cachePropsMap = new HashMap<>();
}

@Getter
public class CacheProps {

    /**
     * Cache Name.
     */
    private String name;
    /**
     * Record statistics
     */
    private Boolean recordStats = true;
    /**
     * Initial capacity. Warmup placeholder.
     */
    private Integer initialCapacity = 200;
    /**
     * Maximum size/entries.
     */
    private Long maximumSize = 1000L;
    /**
     * Expire calculated from last access.
     */
}

cache.cfg.cache-props-map.default.name=default
cache.cfg.cache-props-map.default.max-size=1000
cache.cfg.cache-props-map.c1.name=c1
cache.cfg.cache-props-map.c1.max-size=500
cache.cfg.cache-props-map.c2.name=c2
cache.cfg.cache-props-map.c2.max-size=10000
```

Answer (score 1):

This isn't supported at the moment. You may want to add your use case to https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/9945.

Comment: Thanks @Andy ,I upvoted your issue yesterday already. The use-case stays the same. Might just have to write our own lib.